# How to select rows for each group whose value are within certain limits?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set like this:

```py
dfdict = {
    'year' : [2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022],
    'value' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(dfdict)
```

I also have a dictionary whose keys are years and values are the limit values of each year I want to apply a condition:

```py
limitdict = {
    '2021' : [2, 4],
    '2022' : [7, 8]
}
```

How can I show the rows of `df` whose values for each year are either smaller than the lower limit or larger than the upper limit of the `limitdict`? The result will look like:

```py
    year    value
0   2021    1
4   2021    5
5   2022    6
8   2022    9
9   2022    10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible solution:

```
# astype is needed because your dictionary keys are strings
year = df['year'].astype('str')

df[(
  df['value'].lt([limitdict[x][0] for x in year]) |
  df['value'].gt([limitdict[x][1] for x in year])
)]
```

---

Or:

```
year = df['year'].astype('str')
z1, z2 = zip(*[limitdict[x] for x in year])
df[(df['value'].lt(z1) |  df['value'].gt(z2))]
```

---

Output:

```
   year  value
0  2021      1
4  2021      5
5  2022      6
8  2022      9
9  2022     10
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest splitting the dataframe by year and then using `between` to filter out values in the range specified in the `limitdict`. Note that I am using the `~` symbol to filter out values *within* the range specified in the `limitdic`: `df_year[~df_year.value.between(limitdict[str(year)][0],limitdict[str(year)][1])]`.

```
list_of_dataframes = []
for year in df.year.unique():
    df_year = df[df.year == year]
    list_of_dataframes.append(df_year[~df_year.value.between(limitdict[str(year)][0],limitdict[str(year)][1])])
output_df = pd.concat(list_of_dataframes)
```

This returns:

```
year    value
0   2021    1
4   2021    5
5   2022    6
8   2022    9
9   2022    10
```